Cofibrant replacement in coarse model structure onG-spaces
This question is about the Borel model category structure on $G$-spaces for a topological group $G$. This is also sometimes called the coarse projective model structure.
In this article
https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Borel+model+structure#cofibrations_and_cofibrant_replacement
on nlab, they clame that for a $X$ a $G$-space the space $EG\times X$ with diagonal $G$-action is cofibrant in this model structure. Sadly, they don't give an argument for this. They state as if it weren't hard to prove and would follow from the fact that $G\times - $ is a left Quillen adjoint to the forgetful functor to spaces with the Quillen model structure. Can someone tell me how to prove this?
In the case of $G$-being a finite group and $X$ a $G$-CW-complex I can give an argument: The product $EG \times X$ is a again a $G$-Cw-complex (right type of G-action) and the action on $EG \times X$ is free, so all the equivariant cells are of type $G\times D^n$ and therefore $EG\times X$ is coribrant.
